# Example of a fact about divisors on a surfare

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Could you please give me a nice example of the following fact?
Let $X$ be an algebraic surface, let $D$ be a divisor on it and let $C$ be a curve not included in the support of $D$. Then
$$
\dim \frac{ \mathcal{L}(D)}{\mathcal{L}(D-C)} \leq D \cdot C +1
$$
where on the right hand side we have the intersection multiplicity.

I have tried this cases but I was not able to figure them out: a line (as $D$) and a smooth conic/cubic (as $C$) on a plane.

Is it also possible to give some examples of this on quadric surfaces?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $C$ is a complete irreducible curve, 
 let $k(C)$ its function field,

Think to $C\cap D =\sum_{j=1}^J n_j  P_j$ as a divisor on $C$.

If $f\in \mathcal{L}(D)$ then its image in $k(C)$ is in $\mathcal{L}_C(\sum_{j=1}^J n_j P_j)$, that space is at most $\sum_{j=1}^J n_j \deg(P_j)+1=C.D+1$ dimensional.

The kernel of the map $\mathcal{L}(D)\to k(C)$ is $\mathcal{L}(D-C)$.